# Problem on condition with window.setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website which has a loading page that lasts 5 seconds where you can choose if you want to activate the autoplay or not. Even when I do a condition, the autoplay still runs for some reason. Here's the code, hopefully someone can help.

```css
body .loading {
  text-align: center;
}

body #content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="loading">
    <input type="button" value="Click Here to mute" class="autoplay" id="autoplayno" />
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="iframesc" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/334742776&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true&start_track=1"
      allow="autoplay"></iframe>
  </div>

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--Loading Page-->
<script>
  $(".loading").fadeOut(5000, function() {
    $("#content").fadeIn(2000);
  });
</script>

<!--The script which is not working-->
<script>
  var hasBeenClicked = false;
  $("#autoplayno").click(function() {
    hasBeenClicked = true;
  });

  if (hasBeenClicked) {
    $("#iframesc").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/334742776&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true&start_track=1");
    $("#autoplayno").attr("value", "Sound mutted");
  } else {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $("#iframesc").attr("src", "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/users/334742776&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=true&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true&start_track=1")
    }, 4000)
  }
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: Your page does not include jquery...?

Comment: Yes it does, sorry I forgot to put it in there.

Comment: There's still an obvious error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function`. You're using jQuery slim. It does not have a `fadeOut()` method. Use the full version of jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasBeenClicked` starts out as `false`.

The `if` condition reads `false`. The `else` branch is run.

At some point in the future, someone might click on the autoplay button and change `hasBeenClicked` to `true` … but you never look at it again, and you have already picked the URL you are using.

Possibly you want to put the *entire* `if` section inside a function you pass to `setTimeout` instead of putting the contents of the `else` branch in `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thank you ! Works like a charm. I just transfered the .attr in the click function in order to change it as soon as the button is clicked. Anyway, thanks again.